# Restful API Design Document

Tags: api, rest, document

As a part of my homework, i have to do this:

> You need to send us a design document on how you would implement a restfull API for an online store. It should support addition, deletion, editing and searching a product. You are free to assume every thing else but make sure you document them. Make sure you have considered things like authentication (only authenticated users can add / view / edit / delete items). You are creating the API for a mobile developer who will use it to create a mobile app. Would be great if you can also include some example scenarios along with the expected request / response objects.

I was unfamiliar about restful api's but have now read about them and understand all the basic fundamentals well. I am just unsure of what am i required to do in the above problem?

Do i have to provide code for the API like on this web page, http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

or i dont have to code but i have to explain the implementation of the code in English?

or do i just have to state the resources, their representations, the different types of actions on the different types of uri's and the corresponding responses.

I understand REST but i am just unsure of what this question has asked me to do?

What exactly is a design document, for a RESTFUL API.

Answer (score 3):

when in business, design doc usually means you're planning the technical process / structure of a feature, and you explain the benefits and possible pitfalls, etc. its really hard to tell whether or not your teacher actually is talking about API design in that regard. mostly, he's probably wanting you to list all of the API urls and explain which method is for each, and what their functions are.

chances are, if he means RESTful api design in the latter meaning, then its probably similar to how Rails displays their routes:

[image]